# Compare Listbox and Textbox for duplicates

Tags: .net

I'm using VS 2015 (.net). Currently my project includes 2 Listboxes and 1 Textbox.

My code queries a sql database for ID's and displays the results in Listbox1. The textbox will be used for entering specific ID's manually.

**Now here is where I am getting stuck**:

I would like to compare the listbox1 and textbox to check for any duplicates. If there are duplicates, then I would like the results to be displayed in listbox2.

Can this be done? I have tried to find how to do this but I can't find anything.

Here's my code for the button:

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
  Dim result As List(Of String) = (From s1 As String In TextBox1.Text Where Not Me.ListBox1.Items.Contains(s1) Select s1).ToList()
  For Each l In result
    ListBox3.Items.Add(l) 
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post some code...

Comment: Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click

        Dim result As List(Of String) = (From s1 As String In TextBox1.Text Where Not Me.ListBox1.Items.Contains(s1) Select s1).ToList()
        For Each l In result
            ListBox3.Items.Add(l)
        Next

    End Sub